# Looking for an app that will download HTML and all resources

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos

Does such an app exist that will download all the HTML from a webpage along with the CSS, Images, JS, etc.

A bonus feature would be if it could even rewrite URLs and even grab images referenced in CSS files.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: chrome?  You can download a whole site I believe.

Answer (score 8):

See [HTTrack Website Copier](http://www.httrack.com/).

Description copied from website:

> HTTrack is a free (GPL, libre/free software) and easy-to-use offline
>   browser utility.
>
> It allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a
>   local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML,
>   images, and other files from the server to your computer. HTTrack
>   arranges the original site's relative link-structure. Simply open a
>   page of the "mirrored" website in your browser, and you can browse the
>   site from link to link, as if you were viewing it online. HTTrack can
>   also update an existing mirrored site, and resume interrupted
>   downloads. HTTrack is fully configurable, and has an integrated help
>   system.

Comment: I've used this tool before it works great!

Answer (score 8):

You already have it.

In terminal, type `wget -mk http://www.example.com`

`-m` is mirror mode, `-k` converts hrefs for local viewing

**edit**

I may have made an assumption since I had it, but I have developer tools and macports installed, so I have a lot of things some people may not have.

to install wget if you don't have it:

```
mkdir src
cd src
curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz
tar xvfz wget-latest.tar.gz
cd wget-1.11.3
./configure
sudo make install
```

Comment: I was trying on windows, I am able to do via http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Answer (score 2):

Most modern browsers can do exactly what you're looking for. In Firefox, for example, you could click on `Save Page As` and save the complete web page, with all of the images, js, and css.

Something like [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) would also provide the functionality that you're looking for.