# How to download the complete html page in JS/React-Native?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

So I am trying to download a complete HTML page in a React-Native app , so that the user can view the page later when they are offline too. I am rendering the page using WebView and it works without any issues when online.

For getting it offline, I am doing a axios.get to fetch the page and I'm storing it. But when I'm rendering this page I noticed that its missing all the css/images since, they were not part of the GET request. How can I download the complete HTML page and render it as it were online?

I'm not able to think of any way to download all the page's assets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download all referenced assets and possibly change references so they work locally. There are a few tools that can do this.

The simplest way is probably by saving the website using your web browser. This may or may not work the way you expect but it’s worth trying.

If it’s not enough, try tools like HTTrack or wget. Instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421046/looking-for-an-app-that-will-download-html-and-all-resources).

Comment: That would work on a desktop, but what if I want to store the webpage inside my React-Native app?

Comment: Can’t you download it on desktop, then store the files inside your app? Or do you want to download the files dynamically?

Comment: I have to download it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with React Native, you might want to take a look into a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78140990/3332428), about fetching pages using axios and persisting data in order to render a WebView.

But long-story short: `Axios`

You can download HTML pages using axios. For that, you may add axios package into your project:

```
yarn add axios
```

or

```
npm install --save axios
```

You can find [Axios documentation here](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro).

Then you just import it and fetch as the following code describes:

```
import axios from 'axios'

// some code...

// you use GET method to retrieve the HTML page
axios
  .get('http://your.url.com/replace/this')
  .then((response) => {
    const yourPage = response.data //data is the body itself, you may want to explore the response fields, such as header

    // here you could persist this on a Store or send it to your backend, whatever suits you best

  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))

// but if you're using it inside an async function, you might want to take a more classical js approach

async function XYZ() {
  // to keep an order of events, inside an async function, you can use await and store it directly in a variable
  // but make sure to keep it inside a try-catch block
  try {
    const response = axios.get('http://your.url.com/replace/this')
    
    // more code
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

}
```