# How do I make a WebView display even when offline?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I want a WebView component to display both when online and offline. When online, I want it to use the url I have provided. I want the locally saved/Cached so it can also be displayed when offline. Here's a code example:

```
`import React from 'react';    
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';    
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';    

function App() {    
  return (    
    <WebView style={styles.container}    
      source={{ uri: 'https://wikipedia.org' }}      //a random example
    />    
  );    
};    

const styles = StyleSheet.create({    
  container: {    
    flex: 1,    
    backgroundColor: '#fff',    
    alignItems: 'center',    
    justifyContent: 'center'    
  },    
})    

export default App;`
```

I tried using different dependencies but failed. I'm pretty new to react-native, please don't make it too complex when answering.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about caching right?

```
<Webview cacheEnabled={true} />
```

But, you don't need that because the default is `true`

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#cacheenabled

First, you have to understand…

- The user needs to load the caches (online)
- Then when the user is offline, so use the cache (Your target website needs to do that)

BTW: I don't think you need to show the diff URLs between online/offline, because the WebView will show the message anyway.

But you can play around `source` (which is another question)

```
<WebView
  source={{ html: '<h1>This is a static HTML source!</h1>' }}
/>
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted the webpages to be automatically saved as cache data or any way, but I want them to be displayed in webview instead of displaying the error when offline. I'm not being able to have the cached version of the webpage display.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you want to conditionally chose between an external URL and a local file, depending if you're online or not.

As described in [this answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62498662/3332428) you can import [netInfo](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo) from react-native-community and check through `netInfo.isConnected`.

Since you're not using `react-native-community` you can insert netinfo separately into your project:

```bash
yarn add @react-native-community/netinfo
```

or

```bash
npm install --save @react-native-community/netinfo
```

### Edit (fetch/store dynamically)

Since you want to fetch and store your URL over sessions, you may download it using [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro).
Add axios package into your project:

```bash
yarn add axios
```

or

```bash
npm install --save axios
```

Now you're able to make requisitions (including GET, which returns the page)

Then you can change the source parameter of your WebView component as described in [this answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48553235/3332428).

So the code goes like the following:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useNetInfo } from "@react-native-community/netinfo"; 
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

//**  I'm assuming you working w/ redux, but I recommend Zustand, since I find it easier and cleaner to work with **//
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const WV_URL = 'https://wikipedia.org';

function App() {
  const { isConnected } = useNetInfo();

  //** Insert your local page when you don't have connection, neither a stored page **//
  const localSource = require("./resources/index.html")

  //**  I'm assuming that's your store structure, so change it to fit best your current project **//
  //** Here you retrieve from your store **//  
  const storedWebViewPage = useSelector((state) => state.storedWebViewPage);
  
  //** The useEffect hook will update your page if you're online **//
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isConnected) {
      return ; //** this prevents the code from trying to download the page if there's no connection **//
    }

    //** downloads the page and stores it **//
    axios
      .get(WV_URL)
      .then((response) => {
        const downloadedPage = response.data;

        // --  Again, I'm assuming that's your store structure, so change it to fit best your current project -- //
        //** Calls an action to store your retrieved page **//
        dispatch({ type: 'STORE_WEBVIEW_PAGE', payload: downloadedPage });
        
      })
    .catch((error) => console.log(`Error fetching WebView Page: ${error}`));
  //** bellow is your dependency list, the variables that triggers your useEffect hook when they're changed, so far it's only when your connection changes **//
  }, [ isConnected ]);


  //** if there's no storedWebViewPage you may render your predefined page or component, you don't need to stick with WebView here **//
  if (!storedWebViewPage) {
     return (
       <WebView style={styles.container} source={ localSource } />
    )
  }

  //** Then it renders conditionally, according to your connection **//
  return (    
    <WebView style={styles.container}    
      source={ isConnected ? { uri: WV_URL } : storedWebViewPage }
    />    
  );    
};    

const styles = StyleSheet.create({    
  container: {    
    flex: 1,    
    backgroundColor: '#fff',    
    alignItems: 'center',    
    justifyContent: 'center'    
  },    
})    

export default App;
```

In case you don't have a store yet and you want to try Zustand, here's a [nice guide](https://dev.to/abdulsamad/how-to-use-zustands-persist-middleware-in-nextjs-4lb5) and here's [Zustand Docs](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/integrations/persisting-store-data).

But if you need to stick to Redux, then you might need to take a look on Redux-Persist: here's a [nice guide](https://www.dhiwise.com/post/how-to-use-redux-persist-in-react-applications) and here's [Redux-Persist NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) (I did't find a dedicated documentation page)

If you need help undersing the line `source={ isConnected ? { uri: 'https://wikipedia.org' } : localSource }` you can read more about [Conditional Operator here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I actually wanted the app to automatically download/update the html/cache data of the webpages and display them instead of displaying error message when offline. I tried Asyncstorage and I keep doing something wrong, Also tried using RNFS and Expo-file-system, but they didn't work either.

Comment: I'll update the answer after work, but the general idea about what you said is to implement a code or use a lib that downloads the page you want to cache in a persistent storage and load it from this variable, then you call it inside a useEffect according to isConnected...  But if you don't need to persist this over sessions, you can store it on a state inside the component. 
But still, you should have to have a local html or a rendering alternative if your haven't yet retrieved this online page and you're still offline, so the user doesn't get an error.
I'll be back in 10 hours or so GLHF

Comment: @pa-one please, see if my updated answer fits your needs, I'm happy to help ^^